# MySQL procedure writing for data managing

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have db in MySQL, with two tables and I need to make query like this

```
SELECT a.*, b.* from db1.A a1 left join db2.A a2 using(id) where a1.email <> a2.email
```

So i would like to find guys who has non empty `email` field  in `db1.A` table and their emails does not match the same guys email from `db2.A`, and write emails from `db1.A` to `db2.A`.

in the beginning we have

```
db1.A          db2.A
email          email
www@ww.ww      NULL
```

in result ii would like to get

```
db1.A          db2.A
email          email
www@ww.ww      www@ww.ww
```

I can make it with any script language, but can it be done (such tasks) with help only SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me it can be easily achieved by next query:

```
update db2.A a2, db1.A a1 set a2.email=a1.email where a1.id=a2.id and (db2.email is null or db2.email = '') and a1.email <> a2.email;
```

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) expression! It uses the second argument when the first is `NULL`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, ISNULL(b.columnName, a.columnName) as 'columnName'
from db1.A a1
left join db2.A a2 using(id)
where a1.email <> a2.email
```

---

You'll have to replace the `columnName` by the real column names, and do it for every column that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You want an update statement.

Mysql uses a slightly non-standard syntax for update (which I have a tendency to forget).  I think the right syntax is:

```
update db2
    from db1
    set db2.email = db1.email
    where db1.id = db2.id and (db2.email is null or db2.email <> db1.email)
```

Comment: in that statement you never mentioned TableName

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the is not null condition?

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
from db1.A a1 
left join db2.A a2 
using(id)
 where a1.email <> a2.email
and (a1.mail is not null and a2.mail is not)
```